# List has no rows for assignment to SObject - Controller Extension

Tags: apex, controller-extension

I've spent several hours today trying to figure this out and running through several online resources here and SFDC forums to no avail.

I keep getting the following error:

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject 
>   An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Here is my code:

```
public class SubscriptionAddProdExtension {

    private Final Subscription__c sub;

    public ApexPages.StandardController thisAddProdController {get; set;}
    public Subscription_Additional_Products__c sAddProd {get; set;}

    public ApexPages.StandardController standardContactController;

    public SubscriptionAddProdExtension(ApexPages.StandardController cntrl) { 

        this.sub = (Subscription__c)cntrl.getRecord();

        List<Subscription_Additional_Products__c> sap = [SELECT Name, Id, Expiry_Date__c, Subscription__c, Tax_Type__c, Name__c FROM Subscription_Additional_Products__c WHERE Subscription__c =:this.sub.Id];
        if(sap.size() >0 ){
            system.debug('Retrieved Subscription_Additional_Products__c ' + SAddProd.id);
            return;
        }
        if(sap.size() == null ){
            system.debug('Retrieved Subscription_Additional_Products__c ' + SAddProd.id);
            return;
        }
        else{

        sAddProd = [SELECT Name, Id, Expiry_Date__c, Subscription__c, Tax_Type__c, Name__c
        FROM Subscription_Additional_Products__c WHERE Subscription__c = :this.sub.Id ];
        system.debug('Displaying ' + SAddProd.id);

        thisAddProdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(sAddProd);
        }
    }
        public pageReference doSaveAll() {
            standardContactController.save();
            thisAddProdController.save();
            return null;
        }
}
```

VisualForce Markup:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Aditional Products" mode="edit" >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Product Details" columns="2" >
        <apex:outputField value="{!sAddProd.Name}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!sAddProd.Tax_Type__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!sAddProd.Expiry_Date__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!sAddProd.Name__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Try instantiating the list sAddProd instead, as you have for sap list

Comment: sap.size() will never be null.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `cntrl.getId()` instead. Calling `cntrl.getRecord()` only pulls in the fields included on your page. Everywhere you have `this.sub.Id`, change it to `cntrl.getId()`.

That said, you are never *guaranteed* to have a child record. The standard approach to querying for a single record whose existence is not guaranteed is to query to a list, then check if it is empty:

```
List<ChildObject__c> candidates = [
    SELECT ... FROM ChildObject__c
    WHERE Parent__c = :controller.getId()
    LIMIT 1
];
if (!candidates.isEmpty())
    childRecord = candidates[0];
```

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson, I did as you said, made those changes, minus the getId.  It doesn't give the error, still works, but those that don't have a child record show data.  Interesting, I'm sure it has to do with getId.  Side note, I tried your method getId and it gave me an issue.  Not sure if I should write a separate question for that, or I can try to add it again and let you know what error it gave me.  Appreciate the tips!

Comment: @LouisHM Did you try to use `controller.getId()` instead of `cntrl.getId()`? My post is actually crafted to discourage copy pasta.

Comment: I too am still learning. I've [moved this conversation to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60410/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-list-has-no-rows-for-assignment-to-sobject) so we can continue it without cluttering the comments.

Comment: This is what I get --> ***classes/SubscriptionAddProdExtension.cls: Incompatible types since an instance of String is never an instance of Subscription__c (Line: 12, Column: 20) ***